# annihilation and creation operators permutation rule

Tags: operators

To derive the semi-conductor Bloch equations you need to use the fact that :

$a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}ba=a^{\dagger}ab^{\dagger}b$

where $^{\dagger}$ denotes the adjoint.

**How do you prove this permutation property?**

I recall that $a$, $a^{\dagger}$ and $b$, $b^{\dagger}$ are the annihilation and creation operators for the conduction electrons and valence holes respectively. Consequently, $[b,b^{\dagger}]=[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$.

Comment: Commute $a$ leftward through $b$ and $b^{\dagger}$. $[a,b]=0$ and $[a,b^{\dagger}]=0$ because $a$ and $b$ belong to different states. Does this help?

Comment: That proves it indeed! though I do not understand what do you mean by "belong to different states". Do you mean, " do not share same eigen vectors". What is the general rule to determine if 2 operators commute based on the knowledge of their Eigen vectors?

Comment: Yes. More precisely, the states are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write - for instance - $a^\dagger$ and $a$ in terms of $x$ and $p_x$ but use $y$ and $p_y$ for $b^\dagger$ and $b$.  This should make it clear the $a$'s and $b$'s commute.